# Filterable Column Headers misaligned in DT in R

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am working on a shiny app where I am showing some data in a table using the `DT` package. Here's some test data:

```
structure(list(UID = c("837_12612", "838_12613", "839_12616", 
"840_12668", "841_12702", "842_12825"), VoyageNo = c(9L, 9L, 
8L, 5L, 10L, 10L), EmploymentStatus = c("Unfixed", "Unfixed", 
"Unfixed", "Unfixed", "Unfixed", "Unfixed"), OpenPort = c("ROTTERDAM", 
"DAR ES SALAAM", "LAGOS (NIGERIA)", "HALDIA", "JEBEL ALI", "SANTOS"
), OpenPortDate = c("2001-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2001-01-01", 
"2001-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2001-01-01"), Cargo = c("CONDENSATE/GAS OIL/GAS OIL (FAME FREE)/JET A1", 
"GAS OIL/NAPHTHA/NAPHTHA/GASOLINE/ULSD 10 PPM", "JET A1/GAS OIL/CONDENSATE/CPP", 
"NAPHTHA/GASOLINE/JET A1/GAS OIL/GASOLINE", "JET A1/ULSD 10 PPM/GASOLINE/REFO/GASOLINE", 
"CPP/JET A1/NAPHTHA/GASOLINE/ULSD 10 PPM"), RepositionPort = c("Portname", 
"Portname", "Portname", "Portname", "Portname", "Portname"), 
    RepositionDate = c("2018-08-23", "2018-08-23", "2018-08-23", 
    "2018-08-23", "2018-08-23", "2018-08-23"), CurrentStatus = c("Prompt", 
    "Prompt", "Prompt", "Prompt", "Prompt", "Prompt"), Comments = c("Enter comments", 
    "Enter comments", "Enter comments", "Enter comments", "Enter comments", 
    "Enter comments"), Flag = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No"), VesselName = c("STI Excellence", "STI Excelsior", 
    "STI Experience", "King Douglas", "STI Prestige", "STI Express"
    ), DWT = c(74613, 74665, 74665, 73666, 74996.5, 74665), Type = c("LR1 POOL", 
    "LR1 POOL", "LR1 POOL", "LR1 POOL", "LR1 POOL", "LR1 POOL"
    ), IceClass = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N", "N/A", "N/A"), 
    CompleteGMT = structure(c(17754, 17717, 17741, 17672, 17748, 
    17723), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am then rendering this as a DT with the following arguments:

```
datatable(x,editable=TRUE, rownames=FALSE, selection='none', options=list(scrollX=TRUE), filter='top')
```

While the table renders correctly, as soon as I click on one of the column filters, say DWT, the alignment goes off. See image:[image]

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is a known issue for `scrollX` as you can see [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/)

> **Known Issues of Column Filters** 
>   The position of column filters may be off when scrolling is enabled in the table, e.g. via the options scrollX and/or scrollY. The appearance may be affected by Shiny sliders, as reported in #49.

Keep in mind removing `scrollX` will not solve the problem if you use Filter while your table in *RSudio -> Viewer*, but you can use your Filter normally in a browser.

```
#Works in a browser.
datatable(x,editable=TRUE, rownames=FALSE, selection='none', filter='top')
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the known issue. Unfortunately with so many columns, without the `scrollX` option, the table looks rather ugly when rendered in the Shiny app. Guess will have to look at other tables. Wonder if `rhandsontable` supports column filters...

Comment: You can try `options = list(autoWidth=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks I did try that, but the table width goes way beyond the tabPanel's header.

Comment: Now I remember, I have the same issue with my shiny app.